# how to change color appbar of mapview flutter ?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, flutter, android-mapview

hello I search change the color of the mapview pluggin for flutter.

Here is the link
https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view

If I understand, the plugin call android and ios native code to create the map.
I search on the kotlin code of android but I didn't see any color attribut to change the appbar color. If someone know how to add simple ios android code in the pluggin to change the color it will be perfect. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your styles.xml file at res/values and add the following slyle:

```
<style name="MapViewTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#008000</item>
</style>
```

and refer to this style on your manifest, like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.apptreesoftware.mapview.MapActivity" android:theme="@style/MapViewTheme"/>
```

On the example above I changed the color to green (#008000). Change this value for your desired color.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up a custom theme:

Add to your [styles.xml](https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view/blob/master/example/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml) file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

Replace all `@color/color...` with your color codes where colorPrimary is the color of your AppBar.

For reference, this sets the theme in [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view/blob/master/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml):

```
<activity android:name="com.apptreesoftware.mapview.MapActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
```

And [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) is a documentation about themes.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, but I think I did wrong things because I have no changes.                                                                                                               
 
        <item name="colorPrimary">0xFF3dcbdf</item>
                                                                                                                                                   I tried some color codes, but nothing.

Comment: @QuentinGuichot you may want to share what you did on gist.github.com. Also try flutter run to get this recalculated.

Comment: it's create, https://gist.github.com/nitneuq33000/77508ea902070c9042a0c4985da72d81     no changes with flutter run,

Comment: Your color must be in hex style like `#3f51b5`. Also you should keep the style `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar` and the new one seperated like this: https://gist.github.com/bostrot/d46b75dd1880a05b5f5f4a7021483bb6

Comment: I tried, but no changes. I tried to paste here : flutter_google_map_view/example/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml and I also tried yo paste here :Myapp/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml                                           but no changes

Comment: Try open flutter_google_map_view/example/android with Android Studio (or whatever IDE) as a project and run it again.

Comment: And you need to paste the code in yourProject/../styles.xml. Also if you are using it with your own project that you define the Activity Theme (what i wrote under AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: sorry I tried all,but no changes currently I have made an issues on mapview github. And the solution need to be compatible android and Ios. but thank you for you help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173719/discussion-between-bostrot-and-quentin-guichot).